# what are the things to include in a (ubuntu 20.04 LTS) backup?

Tags: 20.04, backup, directory, restore

People like me who constantly re-installs distro for some reasons doesn't want to go with the same process of setting up the previous environment.(unlike windows where i know what folders and drives needs to be included in backup(although i use AOMEI BACKUPPER) so my life is easy in windows but not so in ubuntu because i'm an avid noob who keeps messing up with system and then re-installs it.

Comment: Look at the "Related" questions in the right pane of this question. Maybe something useful there?

Comment: In the end this is an opinion question I fear.  To me the $HOME directory is all that matters, and I don't see that as very significant anyway (any file I value exists in multiple locations so I'll grab another copy should I need to). I don't backup any system file, should my drive *die* tonight, I'll grab a new drive & clean install & start again (`sudo apt install` when I need tools). I used to keep a list of what packages I was using to aid restoration of programs, but I felt I was carrying bloat so I now just re-install as needed (system is leaner now).

Comment: If you have a spare system, I'd recommend a fresh install on that, and try and use it for your normal tasks. You'll very quickly discover what you need, what matters to you, and leave off all the *bloat* (ie. what you don't need) backups tend to keep hanging around, & have the best answer for your use-case.

Comment: I would advice to create a post install script for all the software you install and delete yourself. You can also do that for settings. Sync browsers with your mail. And execute that after a reinstall. That way you only need to take care of your actual personal files. And I myself put those on a different partition that I mount during reinstall. My reinstall takes 19 minutes (and during it I keep using a browser so my downtime is equal to the booting and rebooting it takes)

Comment: Thanks  everyone for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

To me the $HOME directory is all that matters (ie. my data), and I don't see that as very significant anyway (any file I value exists in multiple locations so I'll grab another copy should I need to).

I don't backup any system file, should my drive *die* tonight, I'll grab a new drive & clean install & start again (`sudo apt install` when I need tools).  I used to keep a list of what packages I was using to aid restoration of programs, but I felt I was carrying bloat so I now just re-install as needed (*system is leaner now I feel*).

If you have a spare system, I'd recommend a fresh install on that, and try and use it for your normal tasks. You'll very quickly discover what you need, what matters to you, and leave off all the *bloat* (ie. what you don't need) & have the best answer for your use-case.

*FYI:  For a non-technical user, this may not be the best advice, sorry I don't know*.

*I used to care about my panel setup & configuration, but every time I setup a new machine I'd end up changing it anyway, so decided it was no slower to start from a clean slate (ie. default setup) to what I need is about the same as restoring a backup*

Comment: This is all opinion - not fact.

Comment: I would claim only the directories in /home/ matter.

Comment: Usually what i want to backup is installed repo apps and other things with my tweaks and settings